# sheduler for checking availability Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to send a request to the site and get data, but they may not be ready. I was thinking of solving this problem via @Scheduled. But the problem is that after a successful receipt, I have to stop requesting. Is this the right approach? If so, how to terminate **@Scheduled** task

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response
  = restTemplate.getForEntity(Url , String.class);
}
```

Comment: @Mukit09 I got the following problem. I can have multiple instances of a task. This task can be for each user. Your option seems to kill all the tasks at once?

Comment: Is the scheduler configured for fixedRate like your question's code? Can't understand how that can be user wise. What do you mean by user? This needs to be elaborated. @WBLord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it can be done. You can use **ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor**. After getting the success response, you can call the **postProcessBeforeDestruction()** method of the class. Here is a sample:

```
public class Scheduler {

    private final ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor processor;
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public Scheduler(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor processor, ApplicationContext context) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void doSchedule() {
        Random random = new Random();
        final int i = random.nextInt() % 5;
        // here you will put your logic to call the the stopScheduler()
        if (i == 3) {
            stopScheduler();
        }
    }

    private void stopScheduler() {
        Scheduler bean = context.getBean(Scheduler.class);
        processor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(bean, "someString");
        log.debug("Scheduler closed!");
    }
}
```